# Forward declaration and parametrized classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a parameterized class let us call it `ParameterizedClass`. When I use it in a header file using forward declaration (`@class ParameterizedClass;`) the compiler outputs this error `Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'ParameterizedClass'` if I declare a property `ParameterizedClass<Type>`.

How can I use parameters while still using forward declaration without importing the class's header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to declare a property of type `ParameterizedClass<Type>` in your header and the compiler complains because all the only declaration of `ParameterizedClass` it knows is non-parameterized (i.e. `@class ParameterizedClass;`.)

I suggest you change your forward declaration to `@class ParameterizedClass<T>;`

You'll then be able to declare your property :
`@property (strong, nonatomic) ParameterizedClass<Type *> * property;`

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you! It didn't occur to me that it would work the same way as the `@interface` declaration works.